# adding and subtracting multiple rows on a single column [SQL]

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, operations

so I have this problem, I am wondering if there is any way to multiple operation  inside [AUGUST312016] column using the RowColumn to the total . This the formula to get the total is:

```
RowNumber1+RowNumber2+RowNumber3+RowNumber4+RowNumber5+RowNumber6-RowNumber8-RowNumber9+RowNumber7
```

[image: RowColumn is place in the first left side]

Comment: Please define which DBMS you are dealing with. By the way, you could very well create a command like `SELECT (CON1 + COL 2 + (COL3/COL4)) FROM ....` which will return a single number calculated from the different columns of each record matching the WHERE condition(s).

Comment: okay but i am looking for the total value of column [August31,2016] using the RowNumbers, take a look at the formula. I am new to this kind of field. Hope you can help me.

Comment: You are saying that within a single column, some of the values need to be added while other need to be subtracted? If the answer is yes, what is the rule that defines which is to add and which is to subtract?

Comment: yes, you get what i mean. I added [RowColumn]column beside [GL SubHead]column to allow me to manipulate what to add and what to subtract the values inside [August312016] by using [RowColumn]column